# view getHeight returning 1 but getWidth is correct

Tags: android, android-layout, zxing

I am drawing a barcode within my app using ZXing.

The layout is an imageview that holds the barcode inside a linear layout.  The imageview's height is 0dp with a weight of 3 (there's a button underneath with a weight of 1).

I'm passing the imageview's getHeight and getWidth as params into the draw barcode method (shown below).

I've tried using global layout listener and view.post to wait for the view's full height, but when I launch in debug mode, I can see that the view is not fully built yet when it calls the draw barcode method.

I've tried both of these in the fragment's onCreateView and onViewCreated:

```
barcodeImage.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int height = barcodeImage.getHeight(); // returns 1
            int width = barcodeImage.getWidth(); // returns correct width
            createBitmapArray(width, height);
        }
    });
```

---

```
barcodeImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                barcodeImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                barcodeImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            int height = barcodeImage.getHeight(); // returns 1
            int width = barcodeImage.getWidth(); // returns correct width
            createBitmapArray(width, height);
        }
    });
```

Here is the method that draws the barcode:

```
private Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) {
        int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        int BLACK = 0xFF000000;

        if (contents == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (format == BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE)
            img_height = (int) (img_height * 1.5);

        Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
        String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contents);
        if (encoding != null) {
            hints = new EnumMap<>(EncodeHintType.class);
            hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
        }
        MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
        BitMatrix result;
        try {
            result = writer.encode(contents, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
        } catch (WriterException | IllegalArgumentException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("" + e);
            return null;
        }
        int width = result.getWidth();
        int height = result.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int offset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Any other way to wait for the weights to be measured ensure the view is built before drawing the barcode (aside from doing a postDelayed which I'm trying to avoid)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getMeassuredHeight() ?